# Showing post and counter in a nesting months under years in a wordpress archive dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I've found this script nesting months under years in a wordpress archive dropdown list.

```
<div class="blog-list-archive">

<?php
/**/
$years = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date)
FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'
AND post_type = 'post' ORDER BY post_date DESC");
foreach($years as $year) :
?>
<li><a href="JavaScript:void()"><?php echo $year; ?></a>

<ul class="archive-sub-menu">
    <?    $months = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(post_date)
    FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'
    AND YEAR(post_date) = '".$year."' ORDER BY post_date DESC");
    foreach($months as $month) :
    ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_month_link($year, $month); ?>">

            <?php echo date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month) );?></a>

        </li>

    <?php endforeach;?>

</ul>
```

```
The output is this :
2014
   January
   October
2013
   January
```

The script is limited and doesn't show the post under that month. I have tried to add it but no luck, i haven't coded for ages and can't figure out the solution. Other than showing posts i've wanted to add a post counter on year ( shows total number of posts on that year ) and month ( shows total number of posts on that month )

---

The jquery script to show the dropdown list

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('.blog-list-archive li ul').hide();
jQuery('.blog-list-archive li a').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    jQuery(this).parent().children('ul').slideDown(250);
    jQuery(this).parent().siblings().children('ul').slideUp(250);
    jQuery(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: This is really a interesting but also a huge question. My idea here would be to get all the posts in one go with a single `WP_Query`, and then take the `$posts` array of posts, rearrange that into a multi dimensional array with year and months as keys. This reordered array can then be used to display your list

Comment: I think that `get_posts` might be a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

As Pieter Goosen suggested multi dimensional array will be the right choice.

Its should look like this.

```
function get_posts_archive_order_date() {
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_date, post_title FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC");

    $archiveArr = array();
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $year = date('Y', strtotime($result->post_date)); // get post year
        $month = date('m', strtotime($result->post_date)); // get post month
        $archiveArr[$year][$month][$result->ID] = $result; // set the array
    }


    foreach($archiveArr as $year=>$months) {
        $total_year = 0;
        foreach($months as $month=>$posts) {
            $total_year = $total_year + count($posts); // set the total posts for this year
        }
        ?>
        <li><a href="JavaScript:void()"><?php echo $year; ?></a><?php echo $total_year; // print total posts for this year ?>
            <ul class="archive-sub-menu">
                <?php foreach($months as $month=>$posts) { ?>
                <?php $total_month = count($posts); //total posts in this month ?> 
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_month_link($year, $month); ?>">
                    <?php echo date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month) ); ?></a> <?php echo $total_month; // print total posts for this month ?>
                    <ul class="archive-sub-menu-posts">
                    <?php foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
}

get_posts_archive_order_date() // run the function
```

Comment: You should rather make use of `get_posts`. One should not make use of custom SQL queries according to coding standards. I did not test your code, but +1 for taking my idea and running with it, exactly what I had in mind :-)

Comment: awesome @Shibi ! works like a charm. Now my problem is the counter for the year and month on how many posts on those 2. I've looked at the $archiveArr as it stores all entries and can possibly setup a counter on it. But i find it hard to implement or the other way put a counter on the foreach loop under the year and moth. –  Jan Bantolinay

Comment: I edit the code i add the counters for year and month.